Concatenate string after grabbing environment variable
I'm trying to concatenate a string with a variable which is in .env file. My .env is this:
API_URL=http://localhost:3030
NODE_ENV=development

And here is my code:
[ ! -f .env ] || export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)

URL="${API_URL}/health"

echo $URL

I expect this to print http://localhost:3030/health. But it prints /healthlocalhost:3030. What am I missing?
Thanks.

Probably your .env file has Windows line endings, so that there's a carriage return before the appended text

... check with cat -A file.env or with file file.env.

@steeldriver you are right. I have recreated by using touch and written the env variables there. It worked. But isn't there any way to get these variables from .env files even if I use Windows line ending? Because I have created this file by using VSCode.

@Raffa yes. All lines ends with ^M$.

Yep, it's Windows style line endings ... Re "isn't there any way to get these variables from .env files even if I use Windows line ending?" ... You can do something similar to [ ! -f .env ] || export $(grep -v '^#' < <(sed 's/\r$//' .env) | xargs) ... But that process substitution would be sort of clumsy and adding to the clumsiness of the command substitution with the unfavorable usage of xargs :)

@Raffa you could omit the grep and just use something like sed -n '/^#/!{s/\r$//;p}' however I agree it's far better to fix at source by setting the vscode's eol

@Raffa I have fixed your code with [ ! -f .env ] || export $(grep -v '^#' .env | sed 's/\r$//' | xargs)
And @steeldriver I agree with you. But this is the vscode's default eol.
Can one of you guys write this as an answer?

@sundowatch Probably a cleaner solution would be relying on the Bash shell capabilities like for example [ ! -f .env ] || while IFS= read -r line; do [[ "$line" =~ ^# ]] || export "${line//$'\r'}"; done <".env"

The issue is that your .env file has Windows (CRLF) line endings instead of the default Unix style LF. That means you end up with a carriage return between the exported variable and the appended text.
I'd strongly recommend fixing the problem at source by configuring vscode to use the correct endings for the OS - however if you must use Windows endings then I'd suggest sourcing the file and marking all its variables for export like this:
if [[ -r .env ]]; then
  set -o allexport
  . <(sed 's/\r$//' .env)
  set +o allexport
fi

rather than trying to manipulate the file with grep and xargs.

That is inspiring as another option with sed's e would run shell commands in a sub-shell and thus the exported variable wont propagate to the current shell :)

@Raffa I had the same idea (to use a while-read loop) as you - then I remembered about allexport ;)

Adding to @steeldriver's mindful answer ...
Since you're using the Bash shell, you could use its RegEx matching capability and its parameter expansion using the C-style escape sequence for $'\r' to match the \r at the end of the lines while reading file lines in a shell loop like this:
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^# ]] || export "${line//$'\r'}"
done <"file"

... and you could use in your code snippet like this:
[ ! -f .env ] || while IFS= read -r line; do [[ "$line" =~ ^# ]] || export "${line//$'\r'}"; done <".env"

All shell builtin and pure Bash.
Notice that unlike the answer by @steeldriver, my answer has the caveat of including, (in the exported variable's value), quotes around the variable assignment string if there were any like var1="string" or var2='string' and although you can remedy that by extending the parameter substitution pattern from "${line//$'\r'}" to "${line//[$'\r'|\"|\']}", you need to keep in mind that this remedy will remove those quotes inside the variable assignment string as well and not just around it … There might be other eval and alike workarounds that I personally feel not safe enough to recommend so skipping those.
